# Stuck "Fetching Resource List" on swagger-ui.html page

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

Getting below error:

[image: Error Logs]

My homepage looks like:

[image: HomePage]

Pom.xml:

[POM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIfp.png)

Comment: It's trying to load API definition from `http://localhost:9090undefined`, which is not a valid URL. Can you post your source code and Swagger UI configuration?

Comment: My config file:Configuration
EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

 @Bean
 public Docket api() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
    .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
    .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
 }
}

Comment: I am getting this error in swagger-ui.min.js

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51132551/edit) and add your code. Don't post code/POM as images, post as it text and use the `{}` button to format as code.

Comment: @Helen These are basic html css files that are autogenerated webjars when I import the swagger-ui dependency in my spring boot project. They have around 300000 lines of code, so it is unable to put it here.